# I would like to view the products by category on the home page Php Mysql

Tags: php, mysqli, view, product, categories

With this I get:

Category 1

Product

Category 1

Product

Category 2

Product

etc...

Here is my new query:

```
<?php
$oldcat = "";
$sql_cat = "SELECT coupons_category.category_id, coupons_category.category_name, coupons_coupons.coupon_category, coupons_coupons.coupon_name, coupons_coupons.prezzo_reale, coupons_coupons.coupon_realvalue, coupons_coupons.acconto,coupons_coupons.gratis,coupons_coupons.coupon_startdate,coupons_coupons.coupon_image,coupons_coupons.coupon_enddate, coupons_coupons.meta_title,coupons_coupons.coupon_id  FROM coupons_category LEFT JOIN coupons_coupons ON coupons_category.category_id=coupons_coupons.coupon_category ORDER BY coupons_category.category_name";
$result_cat = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_cat);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result_cat) > 0) {
    while($row_cat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_cat)) {
    if ($oldcat != $row_cat['category_id'] ) {
    if ($oldcat != "") echo "<br />"; 
    echo "".$row_cat['category_name']."<br />";}
    echo "". $row_cat['coupon_name']."";
    $oldcat = $row_cat['category_id'];
    }       
}
```

Comment: I'd use a single query to retrieve all the items, order by category, JOIN the category table to get the name, and while looping through to display them, check to see if the category has changed since the last one I displayed. If it has, display the new category name. I don't use mysqli, but I have read about some difficulties in using a second query before you've consumed all the results from the previous one - maybe that's affecting things, if it really is an issue.

Comment: Also, don't do 'SELECT * ' if you're only going to use one column from the results. ( That may be just in this sample, maybe you use the rest of the product details somewhere that you've edited out.)

Comment: I have already tried with the JOIN but I don't get the desired result.
I would like to have: 1Category and under the products of the 1st Category, 2, category and under the products of the 2nd category etc ...
Do you have any idea?

Comment: As I said, you can easily do what you need with a join. I'll write it as an answer just so I can put the pseudo-code in a proper layout.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do a single query, and check to see when the category changes in your loop code. Something like:

```
$oldcat = "";
$q = "select * from product where status = 'A' left join category on category.category_id = product.category order by category";
; execute the query
; while $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) { 
  if ($oldcat != $row['category'] ) {
    if ($oldcat != "") echo "<br />"; 
    echo $row['category.category_name'] . "<br />";
    }
  echo $row['product_name'];
  $oldcat = $row['category'];
  }
```

That's pseudo-code, so I've missed out all the irrelevant bits like executing the query, checking it worked, converting the product name and so on. But the idea is that each time you retrieve a row, you check to see if the category changed, and if it did, display the new category name.

Comment: Thank you! I followed your advice for the JOIN and now it works fine. 
I wish you the best!

Comment: Excellent, glad it's working for you.

Comment: Ops... I thought I solved it, but it repeats the category name anyway

Comment: Well, post your code. Can't help without seeing it. Either edit your original question, or post a new one.

Comment: I posted the new code above with the names of the original fields and tables. coupons_category = Category and coupons_coupons = products

Comment: A moderator had deleted my post. I edited the previous post.

Comment: ok now it works I had a $ row wrong. Thanks so much!